# How to provide more than one trusted package to deserialization in .yml?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

When I am creating consumer and trying to deserialize object I got error

> Caused by: IllegalArgumentException: The class 'com.domain.project2.package2.SomeEvent' is not in the trusted packages: [java.util, java.lang, com.domain.project2.package1, com.domain.project2.package2]. If you belive this class is....

My .yml config:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
    producer:
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: org.apache.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
    consumer:
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
    properties:
      spring:
        json:
          trusted:
            packages: 'com.domain.project2.package1, com.domain.project2.package2'
```

Comment: Try removing the space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you mean

```
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
    producer:
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
    consumer:
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
    properties:
      spring:
        json:
          trusted:
            packages: 'com.domain.project2.package1, com.domain.project2.package2'
```

Since you are using the Spring deserializer, not the apache `JsonDeserializer`.

The problem is the space after the comma.

Use `'com.domain.project2.package1,com.domain.project2.package2'`.

We should probably [trim the packages to remove extraneous spaces](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1385).